# Android AESObfuscator limit licensing to specific device?

Tags: android, android-lvl

The class provided in google lvl AESObfuscator  accepts device ID as a parameter. Does that mean that a user with 2 devices will be able to access only using that specific device ID? Do you recommend passing another info instead to enable multi device access for same user?

Thanks

Comment: Do u find the solution from my answer Mr. Snake???

Comment: @Avadhani, nope. You said you were familiar with AESObfuscation. So I did further research and I already posted my answer while ago. I accepted my answer as it was the right one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AESObfusvator is used to encrypt and store information localy (policy class) and it is not used to send encrypted information to the server. There the idea of one user /multiple devices won't be affected and one user can access the app on multiple devices

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You have to Pass another info like appending `ANDROID_ID` with same `Wifi` Address because `ANDROID_ID` is unique for every android device as stated in [AESObfuscation](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/adding-licensing.html#AESObfuscator). It states that

> android.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID, which is unique to each device.

Comment: I am confisued, if android_id is unqiue to each device then 2 devices for the same user will have 2 different androidIDs which means AES will produce different results. I don't think that will help as i want the user to be licensed NOT the device

Comment: I would like to recommend what Android Dev document states. I havent implemented this `AESObfuscation` nowhere yet....

Comment: Hmmm i would wait to see if I get more firm answers. Thanks

Comment: nope. You said you were familiar with AESObfuscation. So I did further research and I already posted my answer while ago. I accepted my answer as it was the right one